# How to make C++ program that is supposed to add up ages and separate it into categories?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm supposed to make a program that counts the number of people in each age group:

- 0-16 (including 16) is infant
- 16-29 is young
- 29-55 is middle
- 55-75 is old
- 75+ is really old

The intervals are closed to the left and open to the right.

I wrote a program that compiles, but does not give me the correct values. I'm new at coding so can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;       

main()
{
    int countinfant, countyoung, countmiddle, countold, countreallyold;
    char age;  
    countinfant=0;     
    countyoung=0;  
    countmiddle=0;     
    countold=0;    
    countreallyold=0;

    cout<< "Please Enter Ages. To end, enter *\n";
    cin.get(age);

    while (age>0 && age != '*')
    {   
        if (age>=0 && age<=16) countinfant = countinfant + 1;     
        if (age>16 && age<=29) countyoung = countyoung + 1;   
        if (age>29 && age<=55) countmiddle = countmiddle + 1;
        if (age>55 && age<=75) countold = countold + 1;    
        if (age>75 && age>=76) countreallyold = countreallyold + 1;
        cin.get(age);
    }

    cout<< "\n The Number of Infant's Are: " << countinfant;
    cout<< "\n The Number of Young's Are: " << countyoung;
    cout<< "\n The Number of Middle's Are: " <<countmiddle;
    cout<< "\n The Number of old's Are: " <<countold;
    cout<< "\n The Number of Really Old's Are: " <<countreallyold;
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the future, please don't add line-numbers to code you post, it makes it hard for us to copy and try out. Instead add *comment* in the code, that you then can reference in the body of the question text. It would also be good to see what input you give the program together with the actual and expected output. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As for your problem, even as a beginner it's important to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through your code, line by line, to see what it actually does while also being able to monitor variables and their contents, and how the variables change as you proceed from one statement to the next.

Comment: "age" should be an integer instead of char. And you also said the ranges are closed on the left and open on the right. So the condition should be e.g. if (age>=55 && age < 75) ...

Comment: `The intervals are closed to the left and open to the right.` means [a;b) kind of intervals, so the comparisons must be ( age>=16 && age<29 ) for all the conditionals

Answer (score 2):

Actually your problem is very easy to figure out once I looked closer at the code.

The [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function of [input streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) read a single *character* and not numbers. So if you enter the character `5` as input it will be read and stored in `age` as a character, and if the encoding used on your system is [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (which is the most common these days) then the value for the character `'5'` is the integer `53`.

You then proceed to use the character you have read as an integer, which as it is encoded will give you the wrong results.

To get the correct values you need to read an integer, however since you want to check for the asterisk to end the input you can't use normal integer input with the `>>` operator, which is why you used `get` I guess. The solution is to use *strings* and check the string for the asterisk, and if not an asterisk [convert the string to an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Something like

```
std::string input;
while (std::cin >> input && input != "*")
{
    int age = std::stoi(input);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you declared age as a char. The program reads the input as a char, so if you enter 0, the value in `age` will be the ASCII code of the character `0`, which is 48 (0x30). You need to declare it as `int age;` and for the exit condition simply enter a negative value, e.g. -1, don't use the '*'.